# Как в Spring зарегистрировать объект-бин, созданный через new?

Tags: java, spring

Можно ли привязать простой объект к контексту во время выполнения?

Comment: Только если создать новый контекст.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`GenericApplicationContext.registerBean()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html#registerBean-java.lang.Class-org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionCustomizer...-) спешит на помощь!

```
// Любым способом получаем ApplicationContext. Самый простой способ -
// за-autowire-ить его туда, откуда вы хотите зарегистрировать новый бин.
GenericApplicationContext applicationContext = ...

// Любым способом создаём объект, который хотим засунуть в контекст.
Service service = new Service();

// Регистрируем его как бин.
applicationContext.registerBean(Service.class, () -> service);

// Не забываем обновить контекст.
applicationContext.refresh();

// Теперь можно вытаскивать ваш объект из контекста!
Service serviceFromContext = applicationContext.getBean(Service.class);
```

Если в контексте уже есть `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` (а он, скорее всего, будет, если вы только не создавали контекст с нуля вручную), то у вашего бина даже будут работать свойства, помеченные аннотацией `@Autowired`.

Если вам нужно зарегистрировать бин, который будет создан Spring-ом (например, вы хотите, чтобы Spring за-autowire-ил аргументы конструктора), вам нужно регистрировать `BeanDefinition`:

```
public class Service {

    private RandomProvider randomProvider;

    @Autowired
    public Service(RandomProvider randomProvider) {
        this.randomProvider = randomProvider;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return randomProvider.getRandom().nextInt();
    }
}

public class RandomProvider {
    public Random getRandom() {
        return new SecureRandom();
    }
}

GenericApplicationContext applicationContext = ...;
applicationContext.registerBean(RandomProvider.class, () -> randomProvider);
BeanDefinition definition = BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(Service.class).getBeanDefinition();
applicationContext.registerBeanDefinition("service", definition);
applicationContext.refresh();

Service serviceFromContext = applicationContext.getBean(Service.class);
System.out.println(serviceFromContext.getNumber());
```

Само собой, Spring сможет за-autowire-ить не только зарегистрированные вами бины, но и те, которые уже есть в контексте.

Comment: крутяк. спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyBean random() {
        return new MyBean();
    }

}
```

Comment: Но при этом ведь бин создастся при старте? Мне же нужно, чтоб он создавался по требованию. Я парсю json в java объект и вот из этого объекта мне нужно сделать бин

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, то Вам нужно, чтобы бин создавался не один раз во время старта приложения, а каждый раз во время вызова бина.
Для этого нужно указать Scope для бина, в вашем случае - это prototype

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Person getPerson() {
    return new Person();
}
```

В таком случае, при каждом вызове будет создаваться новый экземпляр бина.

Ссылки на данную тему:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html